# Inner join with join table to retrieve all CategoryProducts in linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a join table called CategoryProducts with 2 fields (CategoryId, ProductId). I am trying to figure out the correct way to get all product objects within a category.

Here is what I have:

```
// get list of all of the products in a category
public static IEnumerable<Product> GetList(int categoryId)
{
    using (var context = new AppContext())
    {
        var pList= (from p in context.Products
                       join cp in context.CategoryProducts on categoryId equals cp.CategoryId
                       select p).ToList();

        return pList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
  var pList= (from p in context.Products
              join cp in context.CategoryProducts on p.Id equals cp.ProductId
              where cp.CategoryId==categoryId
              select p).ToList();
```

You need to join using some value that are shared in each source and can be compared for equality. Normally In Linq to Entities  is based on the logical relationships between the tables. For example, in your case I thought you had an one to many relationship between `Products` and `CategoryProducts`. The proper way to join is using the PK of `Product` and the FK of the relationship that is on `CategoryProduct`.

Also, if you `CategoryProduct` entity have this structure:

```
public class CategoryProduct
{
   public int ProductId{get;set;}

   public int CategoryId{get;set;}

   public virtual Category Category{get;set;}

   public virtual Product Product{get;set;}
}
```

You can do this:

```
var query= context.CategoryProducts.Where(cp=>cp.CategoryId==categoryId).Select(cp=>cp.Product);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have relationship between those entities then you can just select `Categories` and include `Products`:

```
var result = context.CategoryProducts.
             Where(c=>c.CategoryId == categoryId ).Include(c => c.Products).ToList();
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am not using navigation properties since relationships are not setup in the db I took over.

Comment: @JTunney, products and productcategories without foreign key..cool

Comment: Im working with one messed up database. No relationships are set.